# How to use the cffile upload directly in amazon s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, coldfusion, upload, coldfusion-11, cffile

I want to upload a file into Amazon S3. Is it possible to upload a file into S3 using `cffile action="upload"` in Adobe's ColdFusion server? When I tried uploading a file, it's throwing an error:

> The cause of this exception was:
>   org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Unknown message with code
>   "S3 Error Message."..

My CFFile action code is :

```
<cffile action="upload" 
      filefield = "FileContents" 
      destination = "s3://accessKey:secretAccesskey@bucketname" 
      nameconflict="makeunique" 
      charset="utf-8">
```

What mistake am I making here? How can I use `cffile action="upload"` to upload a file into S3? Some of my friends say that it is working on a Lucee server.

I've also thought about trying to use the `cfhttp` tag to upload into the S3 bucket, but would like to know how to use `cffile action="upload"` and what are the supported cffile actions for Amazon S3.

Could anyone help me understand? Thanks much in advance!

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Comment: @JamesAMohler I'm using current CF version - 11,0,08,298512

Comment: What are the IAM permissions for that accessKey/secretKey combination? Adobe CF's built-in support for S3 requires very broad S3 permissions to be established in IAM. You pretty much have to give S3:* permissions to the IAM user that you're trying to connect with if you want to use CF's built-in support for S3.